# Python - Modifying xml file erases comments

Tags: python, xml

Let's say my xml file looks like this:

```
<Products>
  <Product name="first" />

  <!-- some comment -->
  <Product name="second" />

  <Product name="third" />
</Products>
```

And my script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

elem = ET.Element('Product')
elem.attrib['name'] = 'fourth'

root.append(elem)

tree.write('test.xml')
```

The resulting xml will look like this:

```
<Products>
  <Product name="first" />

  <Product name="second" />

  <Product name="third" />
<Product name="fourth" /></Products>
```

First, the formatting is a little off (spaces and new lines), but the thing that bothers me is that the comment line in not in the new file.

Is there a way to modify a xml file without losing those?

Comment: Please leave a comment if you think it is not a dupe and I will flag for reopening.

Comment: No, I think you are right. I would have prefered not using another library because I cannot be sure if the environment will have lxml installed, but if xml.etree cannot do what I want, I won't have any choice I guess.